# jQuery propagation issue with navigation arrows

Tags: jquery, stoppropagation

Clicking a big image of a trailer (top left) on [my page](http://goo.gl/6MA4UD) opens a lightbox with a larger version of the image. Then, clicking anywhere closes it with this code:

```
$(document).on('click', function() {
    $('#fab_gray').remove();
});
```

However I want to retain the ability to click on navigation left and right arrows (by preventing the lightbox from closing), with this code:

```
$( '#lightbox_left, #lightbox_right' ).click(function( event ) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

But it doesn't work: clicking these elements still triggers the code above and closes the lightbox. Why?

Comment: have you tried **event.preventDefault()**

Comment: It works for me, I literally just grabbed your code, changed $ to jQuery (I don't know if wordpress handles conflicts or something), pasted it on Chromes console and now it won't close the lightbox when clicking the left or right arrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if($(e.target).is("#lightbox_right") || $(e.target).is("#lightbox_left")){ return }
    $('#fab_gray').remove();
});
```

Here we're basically checking if the clicked element is any of those arrow buttons. If it is, then we just return. Else it'll go ahead and remove

Comment: Because of `$(document).on('click'`, you're saying: "Anywhere on the document, listen for a click, when it happens remove `#fab_gray' from the dom. That included your arrow buttons. Now they are excluded

Comment: Sure but stopPropagation() should have dealt with that by creating an exception for the arrow buttons